# Find the Wavy Words!

Tags: code-golf, string

(Note: this is an easier spin-off of my previous challenge [Find the Infinity Words!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/96516/find-the-infinity-words), which is a spin-off of my other previous challenge [Find the Swirling Words!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/95507/find-the-swirling-words) :) )

#### Definition of a *Wavy Word*:

1. If you connect with curves all the characters of a *Wavy Word* on the alphabet (A-Z) you obtain the path of a wave continuously going toward right or toward left and never changing direction, like in the diagrams below.
2. A *Wavy Word* can be:

   - *Raising* if each consecutive character is at the right (on the alphabet) of the previous one.
   - *Decreasing* if each consecutive character is at the left (on the alphabet) of the previous one.
3. All the even connection must be down, all the odd connections must be up.
4. You can ignore upper/lowercase or consider/convert all to upper case or all to lower case.
5. The input words are only characters in the alphabet range of A-Z, no spaces, no punctuation, or symbols.
6. If a word has double characters, like "SPOON", you must collapse the doubles to one character: "SPOON" > "SPON" (because if you go from O to O is zero distance).
7. The *Wavy Words* will contain at least 3 distinct characters (even after doubles collapsing).

#### Here there are some examples:

[image]

#### Task:

Write a full program or function that will take a word from standard input and will output if it is a *Wavy Word* or not, and in positive case, output if it is *raising* or *decreasing*. The output can be `True/False/Null`, `2/1/0`, `1/Null/0`, `-1/0/1`, `NO/WR/WD`, etc, you decide how to represent it.

#### Test cases:

```
WAVY WORDS:
  ADEPT, BEGIN, BILL, BOSS, BOOST, CHIMP,
  KNOW, SPONGE, SPOON, TROLL, WOLF  

ADEPT  > YES > RAISING
BEGIN  > YES > RAISING
BILL   > YES > RAISING
BOSS   > YES > RAISING
BOOST  > YES > RAISING
CHIMP  > YES > RAISING
KNOW   > YES > RAISING
SPONGE > YES > DECREASING
SPOON  > YES > DECREASING
TROLL  > YES > DECREASING
WOLF   > YES > DECREASING

NOT WAVY WORDS:
  WATCH, EARTH, NINON, FOO, BAR, WAVE, SELECTION,
  YES, NO, DEFINITION, WATER, WINE, CODE, AAAHHHH, I, MM, ABCA
```

#### Rules:

- Shortest code wins.

#### Optional Task:

Find, as a list, as many *Wavy Words* as you can in an English dictionary, and the longest as well. You can take for example as reference the complete list of English words [here](https://github.com/dwyl/english-words).

Comment: How did you make the pictures?

Comment: @Oliver With Illustrator because I have it for work, but is possible to obtain similar results with Gimp or Inkskape, or others.

Comment: `NO` and `FOO` aren't valid inputs by your rules.

Comment: @Pietu1998 Yes because of the Definition #7

Comment: They're in the test cases though

Comment: @Pietu1998 They're in the `NOT WAVY WORDS` section though, which is correct..

Comment: @Shebang The spec says `The input words will contain at least 3 distinct characters`, not `Wavy words will contain (...)`

Comment: @Pietu1998 OK thanks for pointing that out, I clarified the Definition #7

Comment: Can you add a test case like `ABCA` which would wrongly pass the test if someone just removed duplicates instead of collapsing runs? (Sorry, I'm too lazy to come up with an actual word with that property right now.)

Comment: Do we have to validate whether rule 5 is satisfied for a word to be wavy? "The input words are only characters in the alphabet range of A-Z, no spaces, no punctuation, or symbols." I thought this was a promise on all inputs, but it's listed under "Definition of a Wavy Word". And, rule 7 requires three distinct letters, and there's non-wavy test cases of that.

Comment: Must there be a single output for each of the three cases?

Comment: @MartinEnder I added "ABCA" to the test cases since the code was edited by others adding more nonense words :)

Comment: @xnor #5 you can assume all the input words are as described, no need to validate. #7 this is the minimum number of letters to make a wave shape. For the rest you decide the output as you prefer.

Comment: I believe  rule 6 is a bad. Instead the line should bounce.

Comment: Can we expect that there are no words that consist of one character repeated? I.e.: Is `AA` or `AAA` possible input or not?

Comment: @Titus the input should be only real English words that you can find in a dictionary so I don't think that such cases exists (even though my question was edited adding nonsense words).

Comment: `aa` and `aaa` are in the list. No idea what they mean; but the answer to my question is No.

Comment: @Titus `aa` is a type of lava found in Hawaii, I think. Not sure about `aaa`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>11</s> 9 bytes (Thanks to Adnan)

```
Dg2›iÇü‹Ù
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=RGcy4oC6acOHw7zigLnDmQ&input=ZWJh)

**Wavy Cases:**

**0** - Decreasing Wavy

**1** - Increasing Wavy

**Not Wavy Cases:**

**[0,1]** - Not wavy, initially decreasing, but then has an increase/equality that broke the pattern.

**[1,0]** - Not wavy, initially increasing, but then has a decrease/equality that broke the pattern

**Input String** - Not possible to be wavy in the first place due to length.

**Explanation:**

```
Dg2›iÇü‹Ù   # Full program

D           # Push 2 copies of input.
 g2›i       # If length is greater than 2. 
     Ç      # Push ASCII values for all characters in the string.
      ü     # Push pairwise array.
       ‹    # Vectorize 1 if negative difference, 0 if positive difference.
        Ù   # Uniquify using right most unique values first.
            # Else just print the string back, letting them know it's not valid input.
```

Comment: @JonathanAllan Dangit... I just saw the comments and changes... I took `The input words will contain at least 3 distinct characters` to mean that I didn't have to handle less than 3 char words. Working on changes, may take awhile; this is my first answer I was able to do in 05AB1E.

Comment: @JonathanAllan Fixed :)! But now you're beating me ;).

Comment: Very nice! One tip, `ü‹` is the same as `ü-0‹` :)

Comment: Hehehe... Man, I may just have to learn python and start helping to expand 05AB1E. This language is impressive. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
OIṠḟ0µL’aQ
```

**[TryItOnline!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=T0nhuaDhuJ8wwrVM4oCZYVE&input=&args=U09NRVRISU5H)** or [run all test cases](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=T0nhuaDhuJ8wwrVM4oCZYVEKxbzDh-KCrA&input=&args=WyJBREVQVCIsIkJFR0lOIiwiQklMTCIsIkJPU1MiLCJCT09TVCIsIkNISU1QIiwiS05PVyIsIlNQT05HRSIsIlNQT09OIiwiVFJPTEwiLCJXT0xGIiwiV0FUQ0giLCJFQVJUSCIsIk5JTk9OIiwiRk9PIiwiQkFSIiwiV0FWRSIsIlNFTEVDVElPTiIsIllFUyIsIk5PIiwiREVGSU5JVElPTiIsIldBVEVSIiwiV0lORSIsIkNPREUiLCJBQUFISEhIIiwiSSIsIk1NIl0)

Returns:
`[1]` for wavy increasing
`[-1]` for wavy decreasing
something else otherwise (`[]`, `[0]`, `[-1,1]`, or `[1,-1]`)

(Declared as unnecessary: For a single value for each `OIṠḟ0µL’aQS` (11 bytes) will return `1`, `-1`, and `0` respectively.)

#### How?

```
OIṠḟ0µL’aQ - Main link: s
O          - cast to ordinals
 I         - incremental differences
  Ṡ        - sign (-1 for decreasing, 0 for no change, 1 for increasing)
   ḟ0      - filter out zeros
     µ     - monadic chain separation
      L    - length
       ’   - decremented
        a  - and
         Q - unique items
```

Comment: Are you allowed to have 3 different possible outputs for the neither case?

Comment: I took "you decide how to represent it" to mean yes, so long as they are different. However your question about rule #5 could invalidate this (and probably every other entry).

Comment: Added an solution to that if need be.

Comment: Can you not just sum the list?

Comment: Oh, yes, of course >_< thanks.

Answer (score 3):

## Python 3, <s>77</s> 75 bytes

```
lambda x:(len(set(x))>2)*(list(x)==sorted(x)or(list(x)==sorted(x)[::-1])*2)
```

Assumes all letters are of the same case.

Returns:

- `0` if not wavy
- `1` if forwards wavy
- `2` if backwards wavy

Removed unnecessary spaces thanks @ETHproductions

Comment: Welcome to PPCG, and nice first answer! However, you also need to make sure that there are at least three distinct chars in the string; if not, it's not a wavy word no matter what.

Comment: Ah, right. Should've looked closer at the definition of a wavy word. Fixed.

Comment: Nice! I'm not a Python expert, but I *think* you can remove the space on either side of the `or`.

Comment: Yep, you're right. Forgot to remove them after surrounding the expressions with parentheses. Thanks for the catch!

Answer (score 3):

### Python 2, 54 bytes

```python
lambda s:[2<len(set(s))<s[::b]==sorted(s)for b in-1,1]
```

Takes input as a list of characters. Outputs:

```python
[False, True] for ascending
[True, False] for descending
[False, False] for neither
```

Checks if the sorted input string equals its original or reverse. Does so by slicing with step sizes of 1 and -1. At the same time, we check whether the word has at least 2 distinct letters.

If "exit with error" can be used an output for the neither case, we can go down to 51 bytes:

```python
lambda s:[s,s[::-(len(set(s))>2)]].index(sorted(s))
```

Comment: Pretty sure you can take a list of characters since it isn't specified as a string: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2216/8478

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>84</s> 81 bytes

```
s=>(new Set(t=[...s]).size>2)*(!t.some((c,i)=>c>s[i+1])-!t.some((c,i)=>c<s[i+1]))
```

Assumes the input is all in the same case. Returns `1` for raising wavy, `-1` for decreasing wavy, `0` or `-0` (both are falsy) for not wavy. Edit: Saved 3 bytes thanks to @RobertHickman.

Comment: I'm not an expert on the newer features, but can you remove `new`?

Comment: @Cyoce Annoyingly the newer features require you to use `new`.

Comment: @Neil, I believe, You can save a byte by initializing another variable inside of the Set() function `t=[...s]` and using t instead of [...s] in those two spots you have it.

Answer (score 3):

## R, <strike>96</strike> 95 bytes

```
function(x,d=diff(rle(utf8ToInt(x))$v))if(any(d>0)&any(d<0)|sum(1|d)<2)3 else`if`(all(d<1),2,1)
```

Returns:

- `1` for wavy and raising
- `2` for wavy and decreasing
- `3` for non-wavy

**Explained**

- `d=diff(rle(utf8ToInt(x))$v)`: Generates a variable `d` by first converting the string into it's `ASCII` values using `utf8ToInt` which conveniently returns a vector. Subsequently perform run length encoding using `rle`. `rle(...)$v` returns the non-repeating values of the sequence (i.e. collapsing all runs). Finally take the difference.
- `if(any(d>0)&any(d<0)|sum(1|d)<2)3`: If at least one of the differences are positive and at least one negative, or if the difference sequence has less than `2` elements (equivalent to the original word having less than 3 characters), the word is non-wavy and return `3`
- ``` else``if``(all(d<1),2,1) ```: Else if all differences are negative, return `2` for wavy and decreasing, else return `1` for wavy and raising.

---

Try all the test cases at [R-fiddle](http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=f2fccZ1G) (note that it's named such that it can be vectorized for the test cases).

Answer (score 3):

### Javascript (ES6), <strike>84</strike> <strike>80</strike> 78 bytes

```
i=>new Set(s=[...i]).size>2?[i,s.reverse().join``].indexOf(s.sort().join``):-1
```

Where wavy increasing is 0, decreasing is 1, and -1 is not wavy.

Thanks to [@Neil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/17602/neil) for helping me save 2 bytes.

Comment: `new Set(s=[...i])` saves you 2 bytes. (It works by iterating `i`, turning it into an array, iterating the array, and turning that into a set. Convoluted but you don't worry about that sort of thing when you're golfing.)

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 12 bytes

```
x*<2lrQ8_BQS
```

[Try it online.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=x*%3C2lrQ8_BQS&input=%22BEGIN%22&test_suite_input=%22ADEPT%22%0A%22BEGIN%22%0A%22BILL%22%0A%22BOSS%22%0A%22BOOST%22%0A%22CHIMP%22%0A%22KNOW%22%0A%22SPONGE%22%0A%22SPOON%22%0A%22TROLL%22%0A%22WOLF%22%0A%22WATCH%22%0A%22EARTH%22%0A%22NINON%22%0A%22BAR%22%0A%22WAVE%22%0A%22SELECTION%22%0A%22YES%22%0A%22DEFINITION%22%0A%22WATER%22%0A%22WINE%22%0A%22CODE%22%0A%22NO%22%0A%22FOO%22&debug=0) [Test suite.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=x*%3C2lrQ8_BQS&input=%22BEGIN%22&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%22ADEPT%22%0A%22BEGIN%22%0A%22BILL%22%0A%22BOSS%22%0A%22BOOST%22%0A%22CHIMP%22%0A%22KNOW%22%0A%22SPONGE%22%0A%22SPOON%22%0A%22TROLL%22%0A%22WOLF%22%0A%22WATCH%22%0A%22EARTH%22%0A%22NINON%22%0A%22BAR%22%0A%22WAVE%22%0A%22SELECTION%22%0A%22YES%22%0A%22DEFINITION%22%0A%22WATER%22%0A%22WINE%22%0A%22CODE%22%0A%22NO%22%0A%22FOO%22&debug=0)

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 96 Bytes

```
for(;($t=$argv[1])[++$i];)$s+=$r[]=$t[$i-1]<=>$t[$i];echo(max($r)-min($r)<2)*(0<=>$s)*(1<$s*$s);
```

or 98 Bytes

```
$s=str_split($t=$argv[1]);sort($s);echo(-($t==strrev($j=join($s)))|$t==$j)*!!count_chars($t,3)[2];
```

0 not wavy
1 raising
-1 decreasing

Comment: `-` instead of `2*` (-1 for decreasing: -1 byte). `*(!!...)` needs no parentheses. (-2)

Comment: `$s*$s>1` instead of `abs($s)>1` (-2)

Comment: @Titus Done Thank You

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, <s>53</s> <s>52</s> 50 bytes

Expects input enclosed in quotes, e.g. `"watch"`

As unnamed lambda:

```python
lambda s:(sum(map(cmp,s[1:],s))+1)/min(len(s)-1,3)
```

Sums the sign of difference between each letters and integer-divides by `len-1`. If all were `1` (increasing) the sum is `len-1` it displays `1`, similar for decreasing `-1` and for mixed `1`,`-1` the sum is smaller than `len-1` so it displays `0`.

-1 byte for changing `cmp,s[1:],s[:-1])` to `cmp,s[1:],s)+1`

Comment: Will return `1` for `"NO"`

Comment: @JonathanAllan `LMNOP` so O is after N which means increasing which means 1

Comment: Yep, but any word of less than 3 characters (after removing any duplicate letters) was defined as not wavy ("NO" is in the not wavy test cases).

Comment: @JonathanAllan fixed the `len` issue, but i the repeating chars are still a problem

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 54 bytes

```
->w{c=w.chars.uniq;c==(s=c.sort)?2:(c==s.reverse)?1:0}
```

Returns `0` if the word is not wavy, `1` if backwards wavy, and `2` if forwards wavy.

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 100 bytes

```
$n=$m=$l=str_split($argv[1]);sort($n);rsort($m);echo(($n==$l)-($m==$l))*(count(array_unique($l))>2);
```

Returns:

- `-1` for wavy, decreasing.
- `0` for not wavy.
- `1` for wavy, raising.

Comment: `!!array_unique($s)[2]` instead of `count(array_unique($l))>2`

Comment: Actually, the problem with that is that array_unique will preverse keys. Thus an input like aaabc will falsely output 0 when using array_unique.

Answer (score 2):

## Groovy - 56 bytes

```
{d=it[0];c=[0]*3;it.each{a->c[(a<=>d)]=1;d=a};c[1..-1]}
```

Outputs `[1,0]` for raising wavy, `[0,1]` for decreasing wavy, `[0,0]` for single character input or `[1,1]` for non-wavy.

*NOTE:* Assumes input is either a String or a char[] and all letters are of the same case.

Answer (score 1):

## C, 164 bytes

```
main(){char s[99];scanf("%s",s);char *c=&s;int p=*c;while(*c^0){if(p>*c){if(c-&s[0]>1)return 0;while(*c^0){if(p<*c)return 0;p=*c;c++;}return 2;}p=*c;c++;}return 1;}
```

Returns 0 if not wawy, 1 if wawy and raising, 2 if decreasing.

Answer (score 1):

### Racket 321 bytes

```
(let*((ld(λ(sl)(for/list((i(sub1(length sl))))(-(list-ref sl(add1 i))(list-ref sl i)))))(l(ld(remove-duplicates(map
(λ(x)(char->integer x))(string->list s)))))(am andmap)(N"Not WAVY")(d displayln))(cond[(<(length l)2)(d N)][(am(λ(x)(>= x 0))l)
(d"YES; RAISING")][(am(λ(x)(<= x 0))l)(d"YES; DECREASING")][else(d N)])))
```

Ungolfed:

```
(define (f s)
  (let*  ((ld (lambda(sl)          ; sub-fn to get differences in list elements
                (for/list ((i (sub1(length sl))))
                  (- (list-ref sl (add1 i))
                     (list-ref sl i) ) )))
          (l (ld
              (remove-duplicates
               (map
                (lambda(x)
                  (char->integer x))
                (string->list s)))))
          (am andmap)
          (N "Not WAVY")
          (d displayln))
    (cond
      [(< (length l) 2)(d N)]
      [(am (lambda(x) (>= x 0)) l) (d "YES; RAISING")]
      [(am (lambda(x) (<= x 0)) l) (d "YES; DECREASING")]
      [else (d N)]
      )))
```

Testing:

```
(f "ADEPT"); > YES > RAISING
(f "BEGIN"); > YES > RAISING
(f "BILL"); > YES > RAISING
(f "BOSS"); > YES > RAISING
(f "BOOST"); > YES > RAISING
(f "CHIMP"); > YES > RAISING
(f "KNOW"); > YES > RAISING
(f "SPONGE"); > YES > DECREASING
(f "SPOON"); > YES > DECREASING
(f "TROLL"); > YES > DECREASING
(f "WOLF"); > YES > DECREASING

(f "WATCH")
(f "EARTH")
(f "NINON")
(f "FOO")
(f "BAR")
(f "WAVE")
(f "SELECTION")
```

Output:

```
YES; RAISING
YES; RAISING
YES; RAISING
YES; RAISING
YES; RAISING
YES; RAISING
YES; RAISING
YES; DECREASING
YES; DECREASING
YES; DECREASING
YES; DECREASING
Not WAVY
Not WAVY
Not WAVY
Not WAVY
Not WAVY
Not WAVY
Not WAVY
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java 7, <s>254</s> 240 bytes

```
import java.util.*;int c(String s){char[]a=s.toCharArray(),x=a.clone();Arrays.sort(x);return s.replaceAll("(.)\\1{1,}","$1").length()<3?0:Arrays.equals(a,x)|Arrays.equals(x,(new StringBuffer(s).reverse()+"").toCharArray())?a[0]>a[1]?1:2:0;}
```

Outputs `0` if the input string isn't wavy, `1` if it's a raising wave, and `2` if it's a decreasing wave.

**Ungolfed & test code:**

[Try it here.](https://ideone.com/AABR2A)

```
import java.util.*;
class M{
  static int c(String s){
    char[] a = s.toCharArray(),
           x = a.clone();
    Arrays.sort(x);
    return s.replaceAll("(.)\\1{1,}", "$1").length() < 3
            ? 0
            : Arrays.equals(a, x) | Arrays.equals(x, (new StringBuffer(s).reverse()+"").toCharArray())
               ? a[0] > a[1]
                  ? 1
                  : 2
               : 0;
  }

  public static void main(String[] a){
    System.out.print(c("ADEPT") + ", ");
    System.out.print(c("BEGIN") + ", ");
    System.out.print(c("BILL") + ", ");
    System.out.print(c("BOSS") + ", ");
    System.out.print(c("BOOST") + ", ");
    System.out.print(c("CHIMP") + ", ");
    System.out.println(c("KNOW"));

    System.out.print(c("SPONGE") + ", ");
    System.out.print(c("SPOON") + ", ");
    System.out.print(c("TROLL") + ", ");
    System.out.println(c("WOLF"));

    System.out.print(c("WATCH") + ", ");
    System.out.print(c("EARTH") + ", ");
    System.out.print(c("NINON") + ", ");
    System.out.print(c("FOO") + ", ");
    System.out.print(c("BAR") + ", ");
    System.out.print(c("WAVE") + ", ");
    System.out.print(c("SELECTION") + ", ");
    System.out.print(c("YES") + ", ");
    System.out.print(c("NO") + ", ");
    System.out.print(c("DEFINITION") + ", ");
    System.out.print(c("WATER") + ", ");
    System.out.print(c("WINE") + ", ");
    System.out.print(c("CODE") + ", ");
    System.out.print(c("AAAHHHH") + ", ");
    System.out.print(c("I") + ", ");
    System.out.print(c("MM") + ", ");
    System.out.println(c("ABCA"));
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2
1, 1, 1, 1
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
```

Comment: `int c(char[]s){int t=s[0],f=s.length,a=1,b=1,i;for(i=1;i<f;){if(s[i]-s[i-1]>=0)++a;if(s[i]-s[i++-1]<1)++b;}return a==f?1:b==f?-1:0;}`(132 bytes)

Comment: Output 1 if wavy raising,output -1 if wavy decreasing,0 if not wavy