# print "Hello, World!"

Tags: code-golf, hello-world, hardware

Yes, really.  **Print** it with a hardware printer  to create a hard copy.

Send the necessary commands/data to your printer such that the following text is printed on a piece of paper:

> Hello, World!

You may use any local- or network-connected printer that is available to you.

If your printer allows, you should use 8pt or greater text in black ink on white paper.

The text should appear on its own line.  It may be left or right positioned as you wish.

Digital photographic/video/GIF evidence of submissions will be helpful.

If your hardware cannot do paper, but allows other exotic hardcopy production such as 3D printing, CNC machining, or [printing at the atomic level](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_(atoms)), then I will happy to accept such interesting submissions.

---

To clarify, the question asks *"Send the necessary commands/data to your printer"*.  The implication of this is that no further user input should be required.  Opening a print dialog is not sufficient.  Existing answers that do this as of 10:48am PST 31st Dec 2016 will be grandfathered (but not upvoted by me).

Comment: Please supply address to which we can send submissions for verification.

Comment: @steenbergh Yep - good point - Digital photographic/video/GIF evidence of submissions should be good enough.

Comment: It's worth noting that many older printers use custom command sets. Most of these print ASCII characters literally, so if you have access to one of the printers in question (or can just claim that you do), sending `Hello, World!` to the printer port should be enough.

Comment: I could swear that I tried `print("Hello, World!")` in the Firefox console once and it opened the print dialogue (useless because I wasn't connected to a printer in any way), but now it just returns the string...

Comment: are xditview, distiller, cups-pdf and other printer simulators considered cheating?

Comment: @Jasen Those are fine for testing, so long as your answer will work with a real printer with no modification

Comment: @ETHproductions in chrome doing `<script>print("Hello, World!")</script>`  does open the print dialog, but without the actual text on it.

Comment: Can submissions open a print dialog box that has to be submitted before the text is printed? Some languages (e.g. JavaScript) can't compete otherwise.

Comment: @ETHproductions No, I want complete automation without additional user input.

Comment: After I read the title, I thought the question was about Python 2. :-(

Comment: Too bad we still don't have postscript answer :-(

Answer (score 42):

### Bash, <s>21</s> 19 bytes

```
lp<<<Hello,\ World!
```

[image: actual printout]

And there it is.

2 bytes saved thanks to [Dennis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/12012/dennis)!

Comment: +1 Valid as a script.  Works fine on my Mac.  If you want to run it directly at the command-line you'll need to change the double-quotes to single-quotes.

Comment: why not have banner to make ot look pretty

Comment: @juggernaut1996 where? Not if I have to print something out again

Answer (score 38):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), 18 bytes

```powershell
'Hello, World!'|lp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/powershell#@6/ukZqTk6@jEJ5flJOiqF6TU/D/PwA)

[image]

Comment: Not sure the point of the TIO link.  +1 anyway.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma I thought it was funny; and it generates the post for me. You can also look at the debug output just to see that it's trying (and failing) to spool the job. :-p

Comment: @DigitalTrauma If you put your address in the input field, TIO will mail you the result.

Comment: @Dennis if I had money to burn I'd submit an answer that uses an API-to-print service. Alas...

Answer (score 19):

### [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 11 bytes

```
'LPRINT `_h
```

Almost forgot I built a 'Hello, World!' command into QBIC...

```
'          Starts a code literal. This used to be "$", finally changed it.
 LPRINT `  Feeds everything from ` to the next ` directly to QBasic. 
           In this case, "LPRINT" and a space
_h         Yields "Hello, World!"
```

Tested and found working identical to my QBasic answer:
[image]

Comment: um.. so what's that link? Is it a language invented by you?

Comment: @eis Yes, I made QBIC. The link is a Google Drive folder with all the code in it - I suck at GitHub... It's an interpreter atop of QBasic (QBIC stands for Quick Basic's Interpreter for Codegolf) and it runs in DosBox. Check out the Showcase-thread for some examples (or just open my profile's answers-page, 75% is in QBIC). WIP, so syntax and tokens occasionally get shifted.

Comment: The OP used a capital "W" to avoid builtin "hello world" ([see also](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/105121/print-hello-world#comment255576_105164)).: building your own builtin command for the job is not code golfing, or you could make it "0 bytes" with a builtin default behavior for that.

Comment: @Cœur: that hardly works nowadays, most newer golfing languages use the capital W precisely because it's standard on PPCG, and it's highly likely that the command was added with no knowledge of this particular challenge (just a guess that more "Hello, World!" challenges would be submitted in the future)

Comment: @Cœur Welcome to PPCG! You may be surprised to learn that you're not the first person to whom that particular concern has occurred. Here's a good place to start reading: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/4867/11261 And further, people who enjoy code golfing spend a lot of time thinking about loopholes: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1061/11261

Answer (score 17):

## Batch, 22 bytes

```
echo Hello, World!>prn
```

This redirects the output of the `echo` command to the [device file PRN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_file#DOS.2C_OS.2F2.2C_and_Windows), meaning that it's sent directly to the default printer (usually LPT1).

I neither have a DOS machine nor a printer, so I'm afraid I can't test this right now, but I'm fairly certain I've done this back in the day. It doesn't work on Windows XP or later.

Comment: This reminds of when I tried to create a file called `con` and was unable to. Ah, the joy of DOS device files...

Comment: NT (and presumable XP etc) can be configured to print this way using the "net" command.  iirc "net use lpt1: something"

Answer (score 16):

## Python 2.7, 43 bytes

```
import os;os.system("lp<<<'Hello, World!'")
```

Not very interesting, though. Here's a more interesting one:

```
import zlib,base64,os;os.system("s=$'%s';lp<<<\"$s\""%zlib.decompress(base64.decodestring("eNqVkk1qxDAMha/yupNgwNfoDboReDPdhQRmrcNXP3bixA3tGEMesj/r5wXoq+YysUemI0BWlYgV\npTyAEDKEQSDucxLxJaj6gUVKE8BFsH2TIOM5iMyrcTIL3YnMqCH4X0TLONTwF3H04Z0XuRPeR3Wi\nxDOi1EZY7gUTWFa8s+z5kTgcnK3sBtbZQRtCt5LPDlrliKouDh5DYz07KB6COuETUL/YRthGxHqZ\nbjyWBAU8EFk6z350Yt97Dol65hxUow9i3zr8YGxFS61nB4szPqvDnS7CU/nFwYLIYczn97JsD3xt\nr+X5wT/ARNN3\n")))
```

Seems a bit too long? Perhaps it's a bit overcomplicated.... :P

[image: A lot of hello world]

**Mod Note** edited the competitive submission to the top for clarity.

Answer (score 15):

## HTML + Javascript, <del>37</del> 34 bytes

```
<body onload=print()>Hello, World!
```

Tested in Safari:

[image]

Thanks to [@jimmy23013](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/25180/jimmy23013) for some savings.

Comment: This appears just to open the print dialog box and not actually send the job to the printer without further manual intervention

Comment: Minor nitpick, the W in world should be capitalized.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma JS cannot do that

Comment: Also, you can shave 9 bytes off by omitting `</script>`.

Comment: Are you sure, @EriktheOutgolfer? Firefox and Chrome evaluates the script code only when the closing tag is met.

Comment: @manatwork Oh, I can't remember well, I just recalled from ≥1 year ago.

Comment: Yeah I tried leaving off the `</script>` and it didn't work.

Comment: -3 bytes: `<body onload=print()>Hello, World!`

Comment: @jimmy23013 Nice! I thought there might be some trick like that but I couldn't quite think what.

Answer (score 14):

## hello + lp + tr, <del>9</del> 15 bytes

```
hello|tr w W|lp
```

I originally had

```
hello|lp
```

But it had the wrong capitalisation on the `w`

`hello` is GNU hello from the Debian package [hello](https://packages.debian.org/sid/hello)

Comment: `hello` prints a lowercase `w`, as is the custom on most programming sites. (I'm not quite sure how the uppercase `W` became standard on PPCG.)

Comment: @ais523 I think uppercase W is standard here precisely to avoid built ins like this.

Comment: If the capitalization is wrong, I'm afraid this is invalid.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I will delete this answer tomorrow.

Comment: How about `hello|tr w W|lp`?

Answer (score 11):

### ZX Spectrum BASIC, 16 bytes

```
LPRINT "Hello, World!"
```

`LPRINT` is a 1-byte keyword in ZX Spectrum BASIC, having codepoint 224.

Comment: can you show a photo of the hardcopy.

Comment: @Jasen In theory I still have the kit around, but it would be a bit of a palaver to dig it out and hook it up to an old enough TV. Sorry about that.

Comment: you could probably type that command "blind".

Answer (score 10):

## MATLAB, <s>40</s> <s>37</s> 36 bytes

Printing text is not something you'd normally do in Matlab, but it can be done.

```
title 'Hello, World!'
axis off;print
```

I saved 3 bytes thanks to Tom Carpenter (use `title` instead of `text(0,0,`. I saved an additional 2 bytes by substiting `title('Hello, World!') with` title 'Hello, World!' followed by a newline instead of a semicolon.

[`title`](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/title.html) adds a title to a figure. If a figure is not yet open, it will be created.

[`axis off`](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axis.html) is used to get rid of the frame and axes, so that the text appears alone.

[`print`](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/print.html) prints the current figure to the default printer if no input arguments are given.

I printed this (successfully according to the dialog box) on my default printer at the office. I can retrieve it there and prove it but you'll have to wait two weeks. After changing the default to a pdf-printer, this is the output:

[image]

^^ Not the correct image anymore.

Answer (score 8):

### QBasic, 21 bytes

```
LPRINT"Hello, World!"
```

`LPRINT` sends text directly to the printer. Unfortunately untested, DosBox doesn't natively support `NET USE`, so I can't reroute `LPT1:` to NovaPDF.

The problems I have...

UPDATE: Tested it in QB64. Resulting PDF opened in Microsoft Edge. Looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score 7):

## 8086 machine code, 28 bytes

```
00000000  be 0f 01 b9 0d 00 31 d2  ac 98 cd 17 e2 fa c3 48  |......1........H|
00000010  65 6c 6c 6f 2c 20 57 6f  72 6c 64 21              |ello, World!|
0000001c
```

Uses the standard `int 0x17` BIOS call. I don't have my dot-matrix printer set up right now so this code is untested.

How it works:

```
            |   org 0x100
            |   use16
be 0f 01    |       mov si, msg         ; source pointer = msg
b9 0d 00    |       mov cx, 13          ; counter = length of msg
31 d2       |       xor dx, dx          ; clear dx
ac          |   @@: lodsb               ; al = *si++
98          |       cbw                 ; sign-extend al->ax (simply clears ah)
cd 17       |       int 0x17            ; send char in al to printer dx
e2 fa       |       loop @b             ; loop while (cx-- > 0)
c3          |       ret
48 65 6c    |   msg db "Hello, World!"
6c 6f 2c    |   
20 57 6f    |   
72 6c 64    |   
21          |
```

Comment: Sure, just added it.

Comment: Now we're talking!

Comment: Absurdly late reply, but a byte can be saved by using `cwd` after `cbw` instead of `xor dx, dx`.

Answer (score 6):

## Stuck + Batch, 5 bytes

Inspired by [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/55425/56477) an empty **stuck** program prints "Hello, World!".

1. Have a printer connected to your computers LPT1 port
2. Create an empty stuck file to be interpreted (filename a)
3. Run the stuck interpretter on the empty file and pipe the result to LPT1

### Code

```
stuck a>LPT1
```

Comment: If you're using multiple languages, you also need to count the glue that connects them together as part of your byte count. I'd count this as 15 for the Batch program, plus 0 due to the need for a 0-byte external file.

Comment: Can you show distinctly the Windows batch script, and explicitly the command used to call Stuck and pass the result to the printer? By explicitly I mean something like `stuck empty > LPT1`. BTW if this uses a REPL I believe the consensus is that should be clearly stated (I believe it's to minimise confusion exactly like this).

Comment: @ais523 I conquer - I should count the glue, and because of that, raised it from 5 bytes to 12

Comment: You can save a byte here by redirecting to PRN instead of LPT1.

Comment: IMO you need to add 1 byte for the 1 byte filename.

Comment: Assuming your default printer is set to `LPT1`, this can be 4 bytes with `stuck stk>PRN`.

Comment: @Makonede Don't edit people's code in order to fix it, leave a comment pointing out the problem and potentially suggesting a fix

Comment: OK, well the problem here is this will print `Usage: python stuck.py program.stk`. Thankfully though, after looking through the source code, naming the file `stk` and then running it with `stuck stk>PRN` will print out `Hello, World!`

Answer (score 6):

## Java, 330 bytes

Golfed:

```java
import java.awt.print.*;void f()throws Throwable{PrinterJob job=PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();job.setPrintable(new Printable(){public int print(java.awt.Graphics g,PageFormat f,int i){if(i==0){((java.awt.Graphics2D)g).translate(f.getImageableX(),f.getImageableY());g.drawString("Hello, World!",0,90);}return i>0?1:0;}});job.print();}
```

Ungolfed (import plus function only):

```java
import java.awt.print.*;

void f() throws Throwable {
  PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
  job.setPrintable(new Printable() {
    public int print(java.awt.Graphics g, PageFormat f, int i) {
      if (i == 0) {
        ((java.awt.Graphics2D) g).translate(f.getImageableX(), f.getImageableY());
        g.drawString("Hello, World!", 0, 90);
      }
      return i > NO_SUCH_PAGE ? 1 : PAGE_EXISTS;
    }
  });
  job.print();
}
```

Java is not a great golfing language, and certain does an exceptionally poor job golfing *anything* hardware-related, printing included.

While testing this program, I set my PDF printer as the default. It worked, but also sent a print job to my laser printer containing 87,792 pages of "Hello, World!" I pulled the paper tray and canceled the job, then retested. It did not happen again. Thanks, Windows 10.

Comment: -7 bytes by changing 3x `job` to `j`, and `i==0` to `i<1`.

Answer (score 4):

### GFA-Basic, 22 bytes

Only tested on an Atari ST emulator with the parallel port redirected to a file. It should work on the [Windows version of GFA-Basic](http://gfabasic32.blogspot.fr/) (which is free), but this is untested.

```
LPRINT "Hello, World!"
```

*Note:* This turns out to be identical to the [QBasic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/105125/58563) syntax.

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript, <strike>37</strike> 36 bytes

```
print(document.write`Hello, World!`)
```

*Saved 15 bytes thanks to @manatwork and @xem!*

Comment: No need to explicitly specify `window`: `document.write('Hello, World!');print()`. Or even shorter: `print(document.write('Hello, World!'))`.

Comment: with ES6 you can even do:  `document.write\`Hello, world!\` ` (more info here: http://xem.github.io/articles/#webspeech)

Comment: Does it print without confirmation? No? Well too bad, it's invalid.

Comment: @CalculatorFeline Why the hostility? If you read the footnote of the challenge you'd see `"...Existing answers that do this as of 10:48am PST 31st Dec 2016 will be grandfathered..."`.

Comment: Oh. I missed that part.

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 29 bytes

```
NotebookPrint@"Hello, World!"
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

### c#, <s>259</s> 250 bytes

```
using System.Drawing;using System.Drawing.Printing;struct p{static void Main(){var p=new PrintDocument();p.PrintPage+=(s,e)=>e.Graphics.DrawString("Hello,World!",new Font("Arial",12),new SolidBrush(Color.Black),new Rectangle(0,0,999,99));p.Print();}}
```

[Example output](http://swdev.co.za/ftp/hello.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

### Batch, 32 bytes

```
echo Hello, World!>t
notepad/P t
```

Should work on all versions of windows with no manual intervention required.

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 50 bytes

Of course we could shell out and use a Batch/Bash solution, but let us instead create a real print job:

```apl
{'X.'⎕WC'Text' 'Hello, World!'⍵⊣'X'⎕WC'Printer'}⍳2
```

`⎕WC` is **W**indows **C**reate object

First we create a printer object (a print job) called `'X'`, then (`⊣`) in that (`'X.'`) we create a text object at `⍵` the argument of the anonymous function `{`…`}`. The argument is `⍳2`, which gives the first two integers (`1 2`) and means 1%  from the top and 2% from the left. When the anonymous function terminates, all its local variables (`X`) are destroyed, which signals to Windows that the print job is ready to be printed:

---

### [image: Print job]

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 55 bytes

```ruby
IO.write(?l,"Hello, World!");`lpr<<?l`
```

For Mac and Linux, your default printer must be set at [localhost:631](http://localhost:631).

For Windows, you need to add an lpr port in your printer settings.

Comment: No need to write to file; you can just send the string to `lp` directly: `\`lp<<<Hello,\ World!\``

Comment: I figured everyone was doing that, so I just used lpr. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Admittedly it *is* boring. There are a few ways to golf your version: `File.write` -> `IO.write`, you can remove `mode:?w`, and you can use backticks instead of `system`.

Answer (score 1):

### Racket 35 bytes

```
(system("echo 'Hello World!'\|lp"))
```

Answer (score 1):

## ZPL ([Zebra Programming Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zebra_(programming_language))), 25 bytes

**Code:**

```
^XA^FDHello, World!^XZ~PS
```

**[Try it online!](http://labelary.com/viewer.html?density=6&width=1&height=1&units=inches&index=0&zpl=%5EXA%5EFDHello%2C%20World!%5EXZ%7EPS)**

**Explanation:**

```
^XA                        # Start Format
    ^FDHello, World!       # Field Data "Hello, World!"
^XZ                        # End Format

~PS                        # Print Start
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3 (Win32), 114 bytes

I used the win32api library to do this.

```
import win32api;open('h.txt', 'w').write('Hello, World!');win32api.ShellExecute(0, 'print', 'h.txt', None, '.', 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Lua, <strike>34</strike> 32 bytes

```lua
os.execute"lp<<<'Hello, World!'"
```

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20861/welcome-to-code-golf-and-coding-challenges-stack-exchange), and nice first answer! Be sure to check out [Tips for golfing in Lua](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/24392/tips-for-golfing-in-lua) for further help on golfing your answers.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! Managed to scrape off 2 bytes from my original answer :)

Answer (score 1):

### HP‑41C series, 44 Bytes

Because this program uses accumulated printer output (`ACA`), the printer’s print mode must be set to *man* (manual).
In *trace* or *norm* (normal) mode the print buffer is printed prematuraly, thus not producing the desired result.
This preparation cannot be programmed.

```
01♦LBL⸆P           5 Bytes    global label requires 4 + n Bytes
02 ⸆H              2 Bytes    set alpha register to the string "H"
03 ACA             2 Bytes    accumulate alpha register contents
04 ⸆ELLO,          6 Bytes    overwrite alpha register again
05 SF 13           2 Bytes    sets lower case flag
06 ACA             2 Bytes    accumulate α‑register and translate to lowercase
07 ⸆ W             3 Bytes
08 CF 13           2 Bytes    disable lowercase translation
09 ACA             2 Bytes
10 ⸆ORLD           5 Bytes    exclamation point cannot be entered via keyboard
11 33              2 Bytes    put character code for `!` into `X` register
12 XTOA            2 Bytes    append character identified by `X` to α‑register
13 SF 13           2 Bytes
14 ACA             2 Bytes
15 PRBUF           2 Bytes    print contents of printer buffer and clear it
16 END             3 Bytes
```

**−1 B**:
You can use the command `ADV` (1 Byte) instead of `PRBUF` (2 Bytes).
The *print buffer* procedure starts printing from the left‑hand margin.
The *advance* procedure prints the buffer right justified.

**−2 B**:
The `END` command allows inspecting the program’s size via catalog 1 and forms a barrier for local label search.
A `RTN` (1 Byte) does not have said characteristics.

Let’s see the program in action:
Note, the [video](https://upload.WikiMedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ec/20240330-hewlettPackard41CX-helloWorld.ogg) actually shows a program with a couple `ADV` inserted before the `END`.
<sub>PS: Yeehaw! This is my 100<sup>th</sup> (programming challenge answer) post!</sub>

Answer (score 0):

## HTML (33)

```
Hello, World!<svg onload=print()>
```

(Prompts a print window in the browser, doesn't print directly)

Comment: Is there a reason the tag has to be `<svg>` specifically, or would any tag work? (Many tags have shorter names.)

Comment: afaik, only svg, img (with a valid src), iframe and body have an onload event triggered when the page is loaded. img without src triggers an onerror event. all in all, the shortest we've found is svg onload=...

Comment: The challenge asks for upper case `W` (not that it changes your byte count).

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript + HTML, 20 bytes

```js
print()
```

```html
Hello, World!
```

Comment: This just opens the print dialog.   Further manual intervention is required to actually print.  Please see the note at the bottom of the question.

Answer (score 0):

## C#, 174 bytes

```c#
namespace System.Drawing.Printing{_=>{var p=new PrintDocument();p.PrintPage+=(s,e)=>e.Graphics.DrawString("Hello, World!",new Font("Onyx",9),Brushes.Black,0,0);p.Print();};}
```

Full/Formatted version:

```c#
namespace System.Drawing.Printing
{
    class P
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Action<float> f = _ =>
            {
                var p = new PrintDocument();
                p.PrintPage += (s, e) =>
                    e.Graphics.DrawString("Hello, World!", new Font("Onyx", 9), Brushes.Black, 0, 0);
                p.Print();
            };

            f(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

### Javascript, 36 bytes

```
print(document.write`Hello, World!`)
```

Comment: This just opens the print dialog.   Further manual intervention is required to actually print.  Please see the note at the bottom of the question.