# Inverse n-bonacci sequence

Tags: code-golf, math, sequence, fibonacci

We all know about the Fibonacci sequence. We start with two 1s and keep getting the next element with the sum of previous two elements.

n-bonacci sequence can be defined in similar way, we start with `n` 1s and take the sum of previous `n` elements to get the next element.

**Challenge**

Given a positive integer `m` > 1, output the smallest `n` of the n-bonacci sequence that contains `m`, and the index of `m` in that sequence (either 0 or 1 indexed).

There should be two integers in output, one will be which n-bonacci sequence the number is in, and another for the 0 or 1-indexed index in it.

I/O is flexible, you may choose to output either list, string or two numbers with optional trailing whitespace.

**Test cases**

First integer is which n-bonacci sequence and second is 0-indexed position:

```
2 -> 2,2
3 -> 2,3
4 -> 4,4
5 -> 2,4
6 -> 6,6
7 -> 4,5
8 -> 2,5
9 -> 3,5
10 -> 10,10
11 -> 6,7
12 -> 12,12
13 -> 2,6
14 -> 14,14
15 -> 8,9
16 -> 16,16
17 -> 3,6
18 -> 18,18
19 -> 10,11
20 -> 20,20
21 -> 2,7
22 -> 22,22
23 -> 12,13
24 -> 24,24
25 -> 4,7
26 -> 26,26
27 -> 14,15
28 -> 28,28
29 -> 8,10
30 -> 30,30
31 -> 3,7
32 -> 32,32
33 -> 5,8
34 -> 2,8
35 -> 18,19
36 -> 36,36
37 -> 10,12
38 -> 38,38
39 -> 20,21
40 -> 40,40
41 -> 6,9
42 -> 42,42
43 -> 22,23
44 -> 44,44
45 -> 12,14
46 -> 46,46
47 -> 24,25
48 -> 48,48
49 -> 4,8
50 -> 50,50
51 -> 26,27
52 -> 52,52
53 -> 14,16
54 -> 54,54
55 -> 2,9
56 -> 56,56
57 -> 3,8
58 -> 58,58
59 -> 30,31
60 -> 60,60
61 -> 16,18
62 -> 62,62
63 -> 32,33
64 -> 64,64
65 -> 5,9
66 -> 66,66
67 -> 34,35
68 -> 68,68
69 -> 18,20
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest answer wins.

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf!](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861) This looks like a reasonably well-specified challenge, but in future we highly recommend using the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2140) to get feedback on your questions before posting them to main.

Comment: May we output the integers in reversed order (first being the indexed position, second being the th n-bonacci sequence)?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen yes you can

Comment: What do you exactly mean with *first occurrence*? The lowest n-bonacci sequence it appears in or the lowest index it has in any n-bonacci?

Comment: @ovs Guessing it's always both since \$n\$ will always appear as the \$n^\text{th}\$ element in the \$n\$-bonacci sequence but may successively occur earlier in earlier sequences? So the *first* occurrence is both the lowest \$n\$-bonacci sequence and the lowest index. But need proof.

Comment: @Noodle I haven't found an example (searched to ~90000) and there might be none, but I think that this is not necessarily the same. **Hypothetical** example: \$100\$ appears in 2-bonacci at index \$10\$ but at index \$9\$ in 3-bonacci (3-bonacci > 2-bonacci starting at index 6)

Comment: Assuming all the answerers understood the problem the same way, I went ahead to edit the question to clarify the parts questioned by Noodle9 and ovs.

Comment: @Bubbler thanks! I couldn't edit so i am sorry

Answer (score 5):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 64 bytes

```
LinearRecurrence[o=1~Table~n,o,#+1]~Table~{n,#}~FirstPosition~#&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n6Zg@98nMy81sSgoNbm0qCg1Lzk1Ot/WsC4kMSkntS5PJ19HWdswFsqtztNRrq1zyywqLgnIL84syczPq1NW@@@SHx1QlJlXEp2noGunkBadFxurowBUq2Cko2BmWRv7HwA)

Comment: you were 1 min faster and of course some bytes shorter ;) nice!

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 17 bytes

```
Lã.ΔR`©Å1λè®L₆O}Q
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASUA2v9vc2FiaWX//0zDoy7OlFJgwqnDhTHOu8Oowq5M4oKGT31R//83) or [Try all cases!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvifnFiiYKeQnJ@SqpdfnJiUmapgY6Og7urvpv7f5/BivXNTghIOrTzcanhu9@EVh9b5PGpq868N/A@U5@JKyy9SyFTIzFOoNtLTM7Os5UrJ51JQKCjKzCtJU1BSNUpR0LVTUFJQyQSKpiZn5ANZCjUK@vkFJfoQq6AUsu1AM/JS/xuBdBrpGHEZQxjGXCYghomOCZcpRMSEywzEMNMx4zKHSJlyWUCkTLksQQxjIMPQAMQyNNAxNAAA)

```python
L                   # range from 1 to the input
 ã                  # all pairs [n,k] where n and k are from the range
                    # this is sorted by the first element
  .Δ                # find the first such pair which satisfies:
    R`              #   reverse and splat, such that n is above k on the stack
      ©             #   store n in the register
       Å1           #   a list of n 1's as a start for the n-bonacci sequence
         λè    }    #   get the kth element of the recursively defined sequence
           ®L       #     push the range [1..n]
             ₆      #     for each of those numbers i, get the ith previous value
              O     #     sum those values
                Q   #   is this equal to the input
```

Comment: Nice answer! I've  just asked OP if the outputs can be in reversed order, in which case it would save the `R`. And unfortunately it doesn't save bytes, but the `©Å1` and `®L` could alternatively be `Å1©` and `®ƶ`, which I thought was a funny coincidence.

Comment: OP just said you can output them in reverse order, so you can remove the `R` for -1 (unless you know an edge case for which this doesn't apply, considering the `.Δ` returns the first pair; it does work for all test cases in your test suite however).

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I'm not sure about that one. A few other answer already seem to use that the lowest n-bonacci that contains the input will be the earliest occurence, but I can't see why that would be the case

Answer (score 5):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>50</s> 42 bytes

```
Ｎθ≔Ｅ⊕θＥι¹ηＦθＵＭη∧κ⊞ＯκΣ…⮌κλ≔§Φη№ιθ⁰ζＩ⟦⌕ηζ⌕ζθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PU7LCsIwELz7FTluoYLi0VMJCD34QI/iIbarCc2j5iHan48bBReW3Z0ZZraTwndO6JxbO6a4S@aKHh7VetaEoO4WtmKE1nYeDdqIPVE1K5iq2bKiXZL05jwjouDcGSNsD7JmDY2hZocU5H5EL6Lz5T4lA/zdaeTSjXDEJ/qAMJCVrkr9k5vY2h5fsFE60k/kyF2ysSQ/SvKCeiL5wStCuQgRzhv1y56I@@5TEV/INeflKs@f@gM) Link is to verbose version of code. Edit: Saved 8 bytes by using @Bubbler's idea of calculating the first `n+i` elements of each `i`-bonacci series. Explanation:

```
Ｎθ
```

Input `n`.

```
≔Ｅ⊕θＥι¹η
```

Create a list of `n+1` lists of `1`s.

```
Ｆθ
```

Repeat `n` times...

```
ＵＭη∧κ⊞ＯκΣ…⮌κλ
```

... append the sum of the latest `k` terms to each list.

```
≔§Φη№ιθ⁰ζ
```

Find the first list which contains `n`.

```
Ｉ⟦⌕ηζ⌕ζθ
```

Output its index and the index of `n` in the list.

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 12 bytes

```
b©1ḋ®;Ɗ¡)Uœi
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY8xTsQwEEX7fwq3SIPk/@04jlbiFrQUaFMsWlEiuAKUewJKGmrqSHAPThIcD@neeMbz5j/M5/PLut4vH/z9els@Dz@vy/vV7ffltK4K1zdBJiSHhLxBtozBXzLKBsUKRm8NqN4aMG2QGjBuxGiMIP3DCPb1lFHgv6GAXcFszGC3VJvArmExtonR9zbqKlZjBafdQaj7FE0Rom8eIY/T8ghKuztB3ahsytDgKdp0N6qYCjTuNw2Qx6umCk1@X4uVujJFSxF3IYbT43F@no@H8BS4Fyv5Bw)

Multidimensional first index rocks again. Outputs `(which n-bonacci sequence, 1-based index in it)`.

#### How it works

```
b©1ḋ®;Ɗ¡)Uœi    Full program; Input = n, the number to search for
        )       For each of i=1..n,
b©1ḋ®;Ɗ¡        Generate i-bonacci sequence up to n+i terms:
b©1               i copies of 1; save it to register
       ¡          Repeat n times:
   ḋ®;Ɗ             Prepend the sum of first 3 terms to the current list
         U      Reverse each list
          œi    Find the multi-dimensional index of the first occurrence of n
```

Answer (score 4):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 105 bytes

```javascript
a=>{for(i=1;i++;)for(j=Array(i).fill(1);(k=eval(j.slice(-i).join`+`))<=a;h=j.push(k))if(k==a)return[i,h]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcrRCsIgFIDh1zmHNWFXBXaCniOCHUTzONGhmxDRs9u6/Pn@wI2rKbJuY7t0R53p9nG5gNCkZRg0/iPQvRR@g6ByEiNMqGEh2zhCUDWKsTAeFrKkeZgRr8TaU1DrXj0siOKOnRiL3faSHnLyz283OdUcrYr5BQ7OiP0H)

### Explanation

```javascript
a => {                            // Defining a function that takes a single argument
  for (i = 1; i++; )              // With the variable i (sequence #) infinitely increasing
    for (                         // Iterate...
      j = Array(i).fill(1);       // Initialise j to array of 1s
      (k =                        // Assigning k to...
        eval(j.slice(-i).join`+`) // Sum of last i elements of j
      ) <= a;                     // Continue with this as long as we haven't passed a number greater than the input
      h = j.push(k)               // Push k to j, and assign h to index in sequence
    ) if( k == a)return[i,h]      // If we've found it, return
}
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 82 bytes

returns 1-indexed

```
(k=2;While[(l=LinearRecurrence[s=1~Table~k,s,#+1])~FreeQ~#,k++];{k,l~Position~#})&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcGxCsMgEADQXwkIJUEhJEOhBCFTpg5pKHQQByuHOTQG1E6l9@v2vcOUHQ5T0JrqZG29HKfXjgFUG@QdI5i0gf2kBNGCynKgp3kHIC@yYHzQHS0J4EFMeM719PUi0HpmLHhGYr/uUteEsTT97Pq52Ux0oEZxvela/w)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 105 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,b=2,p=1,l=[1,1]:l[-1]==n and(b,p)or f(*[n]+[[b,p+1,l+[sum(l[-b:])]],[b+1,b,[1]*-~b]][l[-1]>n])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYwxCsMwDAC/4tGKlUHtUAioHxEaLIJpwVFMmg5d@nXXdLzjuPY5H7tfey9c82ZrDo7GF2xMWFkISZcqMymzh@xrNGywH6HESVyTyOA00iSv9xZHaYuCKooNayik0/w1VflP7q7Q2/H0M5Z4A@g/)

may reach recursion limit, 0-indexed

**Explanation**

Simple recursive search algorithm

- `f` is the recursive function which takes an integer `n`
- Three variables are defined at start

  - `b` is the current number of n-bonacci sequence we are trying, which is initially Fibonacci aka 2
  - `p` is the 0-indexed position of current value we are trying which is also set to 1
  - `l` is the list from which will contain the `b`-bonacci numbers, which is for Fibonacci is `[1,1]`
- If the tail/last element of `l` is equal to `n` (tail of `l` is the last computed `b-bonacci` number)

  - We found our element so we return `b` and `p`
- Else

  - (We hold the possible values for the new recursive call as 2 lists in a list and index them with condition, get it and unpack on `f` to make recursive call)
  - If the tail of `l` is greater than `n`

    - Which means we have exceeded the limit and `n` is not in the current `b`-bonacci sequence, so
    - Make a recursive call with

      - `n` without any changes
      - `b` incremented by 1 to get to the next b-bonacci sequence
      - `p` as the old value of `b` because the search skips the 1s at the beginning so we need to offset by `b`
      - `l` as list of one more 1s (`b` minus 1 times)
  - If less than

    - We need to continue the search in current `b`-bonacci sequence
    - Make a recursive call with

      - `n` without any changes
      - `b` without any changes to continue the search
      - `p` increment by 1 to get to new index
      - Take `b` values from the tail of old `l` with negative indexing, sum them and append to old `l` to pass as new `l`

Answer (score 3):

Lua's a terrible language for code-golfing by any standard, but it was still a ton of fun.

## Lua, 250 bytes

```lua
T=table.unpack function S(t,a)return#t==0 and a or S({T(t,2,#t)},a+t[1])end function f(n,s)a={}for c=1,s do a[c]=1 end::B::l=S({T(a,#a-s+1,#a)},0)if l==n then return s,#a end a[#a+1]=l if l<n then goto B end return f(n,s+1) endprint(f(io.read"*n",2))
```

## Lua, 280 bytes

```lua
function S(t,a)if #t==0 then return a end return S({table.unpack(t,2,#t)},a+t[1]) end function f(n,s)a={} for c=1,s do a[c]=1 end ::B:: l = S({table.unpack(a,(#a-s)+1,#a)},0)if l==n then return s,#a end a[#a+1]=l if l<n then goto B end return f(n,s+1)end print(f(io.read("*n"),2))
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice first answer! Make sure to check out our [tips for golfing in Lua](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/24392/tips-for-golfing-in-lua) to see if there are any ways for you to shorten your code.

Comment: thanks, that reminded me of the ternary operator.

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>81</s> 74 bytes

```ruby
g=->x,y=2{s,n=[1]*y,0
s<<n=s[-y,y].sum while x>n
x<n ?g[x,y+1]:[y,s.size]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NZNNb9swDIbv/BVCekibsa6oD9ou6uy084Bes2DouqANlrpF7GLJEv/2jKYs@PJCIvnoJen956/j5fLS3C4PeGzcqcO2WdF6cUQL3cND23Sr2yMe10X3@Wb@vm53G3NYtnB4aM3Xl5XkfKH1/eqIXdFt/23Ww6XfdH3XzJy5XRqHDnwSHsIoAgaI6SQAj4KRoUxXEap0FaEehRdBdlRkkSwQpYQSSMuTQ3JAE4GBFEEBKQAppcIaSDHESBJRprqiFEUVUgVUZwaBU56z6Cw4SpVLcMmO@HHgfGZ7cEp0AV0AF5MLiVaiY3QMrsxviuCSvQpdBa5O7xNbXpHeohdN6YEleEV66Zz0UJERK/AJOKqYDdTgFegZPYMvsxnJU6Cv0Et8nY0RBCUGi8FCmJpaQ1BikMk4CD4blsGlycnoAoSYzYtWamAMDKHMjYgQlBoqDBWEOjWlgqjMaDFaiJQbVEJUapShO4g@N4shKjXKVsjGTCtTQ1RmZIwSMQ1TaisxVhhF17mbBKxMtsgWmPIaVMDKZNkZB@xznz2wMjkgy3LG1PMaOO2pLCoDJ2ZAH4GVyhWyVKynaTg7K7qP3ba/nv1oZzfF29PH6dyf@3w4hs1uhnTe4v68aov@/ecWF/spZI7zKe1wPujdsB4A9L8qNk/Pr2Ne/4rb34cz7DedacxL8fy02123N/Dx2XdmdnVqB9MszdVJ7gdzd5dU06xSnvyz5quZv/@Zm3szX5jx@/b4@P1R1WI@zGC4/Ac)

- Saved 7Bytes thanks to @Dingus suggestions
- 1 indexed

```
g=-> x,y=2{  # recursive lambda testing each y-fib
               returning the first valid result
s,n=[1]*y,0  # s = current serie initialized to 1's
               n = next term

while x> n   # add terms up to x
=s[-y..-1].sum # which is sum of last y terms
s<<n end     # add it
x==n ?       # if last term is x
[y,s.size]   # return y and length 
:g[x,y+1]}   # else try next y-fib
```

Comment: You can [avoid end](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/28578/92901) by using the modifier form of `while`. `[-y..-1]` can be `[-y,y]` and you can save another byte on the ternary conditional by testing for `x<n` instead and swapping the branches.

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 77 bytes

```javascript
m=>(h=i=>(g=(i,k=n)=>i<k||k&&g(--i)+g(i,k-1))(i)-m?h(i<m?++i:++n):[n,i])(n=2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcwxDoMwDEDRq3RCtkyqNiOJ4SBVB0RJcANOBVUn7p7C8pcvvXf/67dhlc/XaH6NJXBZuIWJ5WhkkDqxIrfi076nqopgjCDFc5g7IgiapZtA/NIRSUOk2Dy0lieCssUS8grC1om3NydEOGTd8jxe53wil3AI6Mof)

Very slow but a bit shorter.

---

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 79 bytes

```javascript
m=>(h=i=>(g=(i,k=n)=>t=i<k||k&&g(--i)+g(i,k-1))(i)-m?h(t<m?++i:++n):[n,i])(n=2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcxBDoIwEEDRq7giMxlqlI0J7cBBjAuCtIylrYHGFXevsPmbn7zP8Bu2cZVvVjG9p2K5BO5gZjnqGKT2HJG7zGL8vvuqcqCUILlzqTsiCKrQz5BN6ImkJYrYPmMtL4TIDRabVhButJjHTQsRjiluaZmuSzqRiz0E1OUP)

A bit faster...

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>139</s></sup> 130 bytes

```c
t;*b;j;s;i;*f(n){b=calloc(n,8);for(t=*b=s=1;t;)for(b[i=s++]=1;t&&n/++i;t=b[i]-n)for(b[j=i]=0;j-->i-s;)b[i]+=b[j];*b++=s;*b=i;--b;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZTRbtowFIbv@xQWUlEgiRo7tknkpTfTnqKNJghJZ9aliEQaWsWrj/3OOaV0KsJgjj8fH3@xadKnpjmfR7fcuJ0bnHfLLuoXr5uqWT8/vzRRnxQL170corFabqqhkm50i/B78@CrIY7rEJnP@7s49m6sEK3TnoFd5esqc7s0vffp4BZhMAayq7FcHFcDvirv0nTjTmffj@LX2vfRQrzeCLxCYGyHcXioRSVeVSLyROhEmETYRKwSUSSiTITM0CQaAAlCApFgJCAJSgKT4BQ4BU6BU@AUOAVOgVPgFDgFLgeXg8vDguBycDm4HFwOLgeXg9PgNDgNTofKwGlwGpwGp8FpcAacAWfAGXAmbAGcAWfAGXAGnAVnwVlwFpwFZ8NewVlwFpwtT@7ipj3u22Zst9/7iyA1CVKTIOrkJMiSH0V6CrKTs5yM5ZCbidM03xIf1BRshsQYylWQlpAhaAlZNK2mOVuwEjIGK1PWgp5hRtkNV2SoWkNVGV4sKAmFBiVhVctP39JTCUZk8ZkR/9@R0VNN5u0d6l1RXbzDkhdiI5L2smIjfFpWbMSQkWnXRIXiyFE4aTnbnpRIUlKyEj4oYc1JiSElBStZsRJLSkpSUrASyUoKVsKnpGQlhpSojJU0P9aHJT7b5md7ICOzx@M39Xgsv6KZWSKuf@cznofLK6Lg0/fb9ohpmePuFzH4P@1LF72fvcUdh5ZXMSfwbxBmvN3ly31GNrrT03DtPowu9xjuonHxMdwjenXYP5vprxH/KbJfDwOo/UNWV1Uv5nN0Jbr@HdsfAHbR7HYr0ntxu03QxO3w2MPUmIg@ET65@Az56qtKu0PbRnsOnG5O579N97x@Gs7p738)

Inputs integer \$n>1\$.
Returns a pointer to an array \$a\$ where \$a[0]=s\$ (the sequence number) and \$a[1]=i\$ (the \$0\$-based index) of the first occurrence of \$n\$ in an \$n\$-bonacci sequence.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 84 bytes

```javascript
f=(n,i=k=2)=>(g=(i,h=j=>j&&g(--i)+h(j-1))=>v=i<k||h(k))(i)-n?f(n,v<n?i+1:!k++):[k,i]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Dcs9DoMwDEDhq7gLshVSFZZKNIaDVB0Q5ccJchBUTNw9zfSGp8/3Z38Mu2w/q/E7pjQxaikcuCZucWaUcmHPrS@KGa0VMgt6W1G@J4sL17VgIEIhq92U7em0E1M1t2AMNe9QyidNcUcFhvoFCg6ej9x8YYh6xHW8r3HOEjInSn8)

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Classic)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 62 bytes

```
{l←1+⍵⋄⊃(,∘.,⍨⍳l)/⍨⍵=,1⌽↑l{⍺{d←⍵⋄({⍵,+/⍵↑⍨-d}⍣(⍺-⍵))d⍴1}¨⍵}⍳l}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##xdC9SsRAFIbh3qtImbCJy5k/3cKLCRtWhIDCVrKkUoKoA25nb2OvaQQbL@XcSDxvvAiLb5gZnnPmp73pm@627a8vm23f7vdX23k@9Dq@yErzpE/3@nhX1vrwelprftf80VfrZTJd1KLP3zoe@4Pmr0NnNX8Vpa2nerVmNR4NN92g@a001dheVXWaP2X4oclAx2HeFVZd/Me57mRXeEuwREuynFnOLRuLCANKYIIToCAFKlgBO7ADO7ADO7ADO7ADO7AH@@V8sAd7sAd7sAd7cAAHcFhuCw7gAA7gAA7gCI7gCI7L28ARHMERHMEJnMAJnMBp@QlwAidw2vwC)

Answer (score 0):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 92 bytes

```r
function(m)while(F<-F+1)for(i in 0:m+1)if((T[i]=`if`(i>F,sum(T[i-1:F]),1))==m)return(c(F,i))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY7BCsIwEETvfsWCl11swVwEi/WYL/AmYtOY4IJJSjZV@vU1HjzOMI83ec3ufY9jiv3q52gLp4iBPk9@OdSnVu8U@ZSRgSPsu1Aje8TLlW/9wH5APutG5vBrWtXpGzWKqO8DZVfmHNGibphoLShmml4Lqu5wbP5Sai3uu0rAZgsyjyUbW0CBzymAakcj7lHND7ZOoP4AZ2QBm8JkMkuKUBIUJwVsXcr6BQ)

Returns 1-based indices.